# Deleting the rows from sqlite db still the values are not getting deleted and size is getting bigger

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am collecting the twitter stream and storing it in a sqlite db.Since the streams are coming and database is getting bigger i executed a command to delete the tweets that are older than a minute.But the tweets are there only and database is getting bigger.Please help since as I am new to sqlite

Here's the code

```
class listener(StreamListener):

def on_data(self,data):
    try:
        data = json.loads(data)
        tweet = unidecode(data['text'])
        text = preprocess(tweet)
        score = predict(text)['score']
        
        created_at = data['created_at']
        

        
        

        c.execute('INSERT INTO sentiment (created_at,tweet,score) VALUES (?,?,?)',(created_at,tweet,score))
        conn.commit()

      
        
        c.execute('DELETE FROM sentiment WHERE created_at IN(SELECT created_at FROM(SELECT 
                  created_at, strftime("%s","now") - strftime("%s",created_at) AS passed_time FROM 
                sentiment WHERE passed_time >=60))')
       
        conn.commit()

    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are testing IN subquery, which in turn has a subquery,
and you're complaining that this complex approach didn't work,
that IN found no matches
among your "seconds since 1970" timestamps.

Ok. Your spec is *much* simpler than that, you said you want

> a command to delete the tweets that are older than a minute

Piece of cake. Just follow that English sentence and turn it into SQL:

```
DELETE FROM sentiment WHERE created_at < strftime('%s', 'now') - 60;
```

Current time minus sixty seconds is a minute ago,
and the WHERE clause asks for rows older than that.